simplify big if-elif nested function
Currently I have function similar to:
def func():
    mychoose = input()
    if mychoose == '1':
        result = 1
    elif mychoose == '2':
        secondchoose = input()
        if secondchoose == '1':
            result = 'another result'
        elif secondchoose == '2':
            result = 'random another result'
    elif mychoose == '3':
        thridchoose = input()
        if secondchoose == '1':
            result = 'some result'
        elif secondchoose == '2':
            result = 'some some result'
        elif secondchoose == '3':
            result = 'result'
    return result

I want to make this code more compact without splitting it into multiple functions. please give me advice on how should I do this.
I have an idea of using list + try/except function:
def func():
  list = [1,2,3]
  try:
    choose = int(input())
    retuen = list[choose-1]
  except ValueError:
    print('wrong value)
    return func()

But have no idea how to use nested functions with it as I used it in if/elif.
Would like to hear advice on what method to use instead of try/except too.

Cant you just combine the inputs as a string and then convert to a int?

What do you mean by similar function? What values are accepted for your first and second digit? Also the code after  elif mychoose == '3': will not work since secondchoose is not defined.

Thats just example and combining them not the case, but overall large construction of code.
By similar function i mean that i have skelet of code like the one in example. Accepted values must be int from 1 to X.

You could use a an array of dictionaries if you have a defined number of steps where each iteration over the array is a step and every dictionary have a match between input and the value (or a callable) and just check the input for each iteration and if something goes wrong just break it ecc... if you want something "elegant". There is also the match-case structure...

If I enter 0, your code will crash. Is that desirable?

You could try using nested dictionaries wouldn't say it's more compact but imo it is more readable. You can do that like this for instance;
choices = {
    '1': 1,
    '2': {
        '1': 21,
        '2': 22
    },
    '3': {
        '1': 31,
        '2': 32,
        '3': 33
    }
}

and then use something like this to choose a value:
mychoose = input()
if mychoose in choices:
    if isinstance(choices[mychoose], dict):
        secondchoose = input()
        result = choices[mychoose].get(secondchoose, "Invalid sub-choice")
    else:
        result = choices[mychoose]
else:
    result = "Invalid choice"

return result


I'd probably do something like this. Although I would probably not differentiate between mychoose and secondchoose and use a recursive function to traverse the dict.

Thanks, thats pretty much solves my problem.

From Python 3.10 onward, you can use structural pattern matching:
def func():
    match input('Choice 1: '), input('Choice 2: '):
        case '1', __:
            return 1
        case '2', '1':
            return 'another result'
        case '2', '2':
            return 'random another result'
        case '3', '1':
            return 'some result'
        case '3', '2':
            return 'some some result'
        case '3', '3':
            return 'result'
        case __:
            raise NotImplementedError

(this is a very simple use of pattern matching, and equivalent to your if-else had you got the two inputs before the if structure)
If you want to conditionally ask for the second input (as you do when the first choice is '1' in your example), you won't escape nesting of some sort.

I think you could use something like this:
first_digit = input()
if first_digit == '1':
    result = 1
else:
    second_digit = input()
    result = 10 * int(first_digit) + int(second_digit) 


Sorry if i misslead you with my example, i corrected it, so the goal is not to combine two ints.
